# font-weight 900 and font-weight 700 are rendered in the same way

Tags: html, css, font-size

I have this sample html file:

```html
<div style="font-weight: 700; font-size: 3em">
    Test font bold (weight = 700)
</div>

<div style="font-weight: 900; font-size: 3em">
    Test font bold (weight = 900)
</div>
```

I do not know why if I change the value of `font-weight` from `900` to `700` I get the same result. The text does have the same size.

While in this MDN docs page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight if I change the value from 900 to 700 (with the browser feature of live css change) I get different results.

Comment: It depends on the font you're using (whether or not it supports specific font weights). Also, when it comes to numerical font weights, there's a problem with many browsers where they only support numerical values in specific steps (larger than a gap of 200, mostly). That problem is explained quite in detail over here: http://clagnut.com/blog/2228/

Comment: which font is the font of the page i linked?

Comment: @GiacomoM - That font is `sans-serif`

Comment: Do you know a font like google Lato that has a weight of 900?

Comment: @MaximilianKrause, it's a bit weird, I have WordPress multisite, and I open 2 different sites in chrome from my multisite, in one site, the font-weight worked properly, but on another, it's not working... before in localhost, it's happening too before upload to hosting, in hosting worked but in localhost not working, only work on regular font-weight (bold, normal, light)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all fonts support all variations of font-weights. If you need something bolder, you would need to choose an alternative font.

Changing your code to have a sans-serif font-family will give you a live example of the difference.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
    div { font-weight: 900; font-size: 3em; font-family: sans-serif }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Test font bold</div>
</body>
</html>
```